# How do agents and teamwork tests work?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, sr5-matrix

Can an agent running on a cyberdeck assist the decker via a teamwork test for relevant matrix actions?

Also, as cyberdecks can only run one copy of a program at a time, does this mean a deck can only run one agent-class program, or would you need two unique agents if you wanted to use two agents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On page 246 of the core, under the Agents heading, it says

> An agent runs as a program and can use programs running on the same device as them.

Therefore even though it counts as its own entity **it is still a program of a specific type**.  You *can* however have multiple different agent programs installed, but they cannot run simultaneously and requires a system reboot to switch since it counts as a persona.  The section then goes on to state:

> When an agent is running, it has its own persona (and icon). An agent is about as smart as a pilot program of the same rating (Pilot Programs, p. 269).

So to continue to explore that, the Pilot Programs section states that:

> and
>   When faced with something novel or unexpected, or a complicated command, a Pilot program
>   must make a Device Rating x 2 Test

Therefore I would say that **teamwork is *possible* with an agent**, but you do so at a risk.  If the target action has a high difficulty rating, the agent program might have to make a test just to attempt to help.  With the right specific commands it can be prepared to help, but I imagine that would take some preset conditions to let it know when to pile on without trouble.